# Server-Client model of Bluetooth LE?

Tags: bluetooth, client-server, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am finding out about BLE on the Internet. I don't understand why everybody use GATT server for the device, such as KIT. And use GATT client for the application on mobile?
Can you explain for me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The roles in Bluetooth are *Central* and *Peripheral*.  Typically the computer/mobile device will have the central role and the Bluetooth device (let's say a heart monitor) will be the peripheral.

The central will initiate a connection to the peripheral.  If you were to think of it in client/server terms, the heart rate monitor is the server (it serves heart rate data) and the mobile application is the client (it is receiving the data) but as I said, this isn't the right terminology for BLE.

BLE devices often have limited or no user interface capability while the mobile device has a touch screen - so it is much easier to discover and connect to a peripheral from a mobile device acting as a central than if the roles were reversed.